# How to check theme has "Articles" folder in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a plugin.

Now my hierarchy is user install my plugin and make a folder "articles" in current theme. And my function paste some files in that folder. Now I don't get the point that how can i check that theme has "articles" folder.

e.g.

```
if(current_theme_has_folder("articles")){
    // do this
}
else{
    // Nothing
}
```

I want like this condition, so I can move some files in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`file_exists()`, PHP function

to check that folder

Comment: Like this 

$var = "/var/www/dev/dev_team/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/articles";

if(file_exists($var)){}